# Upgraded gatsby react font awesome icons from 4 to 5, now the social icons are not working

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I've upgraded my gatsby font awesome icons from 4.7 to 5.12.  Almost all of the icons are working, however the social icons are not, they are just showing a square box.

I downloaded the webpack, I've tried installing it using npm, and nothing I try works.  All the other icons are working except the social ones.

Comment: Did you happen to read [Upgrading from Version 4](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4) on the Font Awesome website? As they say, "[v]ersion 5 has been re-written and re-designed completely from scratch. "

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Font Awesome 5, you will have to be aware that brand icons are now separated into their own style/category for easier use.

Therefore, you will need to install the package for the brand icons on your project.

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

And then, on the component that requires the usage of the icons, you will need to import them.

```
import React from 'react';
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

If you are using the `react-fontawesome` component to mount the icons,

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faLinkedinIn}
  className='icon-class'
/>
```

Do refer to the [upgrade guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I messed up a couple of items during the upgrade.  Since I'm using a gatsby html5up template, I wanted to stay within the same structure that was already there.

First mistake was in my `_mixins.scss`, I needed to remove the `font-family: FontAwesome` reference. I had initially replaced it, but you need to just remove it.

Second mistake, was not referencing the class.  Before the upgrade it wasn't needed, but after the upgrade, I had to add the class for each icon.
Before upgrade:
`className="icon alt fa-linkedin"`
`className="icon alt fa-envelope"`
After upgrade:
`className="icon alt fab fa-linkedin"`
`className="icon alt fas fa-envelope"`

The reason that some icons were showing, while other's weren't, is because I had referenced the free icons font-family in the `_mixins.scss`.  Removing this cause them all the display as squares, until I added the class references for each displayed icon.